# How to print an array of dictionary values into a nice string in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of `routine` objects thats are defined as:

```
struct Routine {
    let routineName: String
    let routineExercisesAndSets: [String: Int]
}

let routines: [Routine] = {
    let firstRoutine = Routine(routineName: "Legs", routineExercisesAndSets: ["Squats":4,"Lunges":4,"Calf Raises":4])

    let secondRoutine = Routine(routineName: "Chest", routineExercisesAndSets: ["Bench Press":4,"Press Ups":4,"Flyes":4,"Inclined Bench Press":4])

    let thirdRoutine = Routine(routineName: "Arms", routineExercisesAndSets: ["Bicep Curls":4,"Hammer Curls":4,"Preacher Curls":4,"Tricep Extension":4,"Tricep Dips":4])

    return [firstRoutine, secondRoutine, thirdRoutine]
}()
```

I am trying to return them `routineExercisesAndSets` array into a `UITableViewCell` as detail text and when using the array.description function I get this result in the tableView

[image: this result in the tableView]

My question is, how could I iterate through the routine objects and print out a 'pretty' formatted string that looks something like:

`"Calf Raises x 4, Squats x 4, Lunges x 4..."`

I can print out the individual key, value pairs on new lines using this code:

```
for i in routines{
    for (key, value) in (i.routineExercisesAndSets)! {
        print("\(key) x \(String(value))")
    }
}
```

which produces:

`Calf Raises x 4
Squats x 4
Lunges x 4
Bench Press x 4
Press Ups x 4
Flyes x 4
Inclined Bench Press x 4
Tricep Extension x 4
Tricep Dips x 4
Preacher Curls x 4
Hammer Curls x 4
Bicep Curls x 4`

but I want to group them by their parent object so the exercises for a routine display on the same line so it looks like the example `"Calf Raises x 4, Squats x 4, Lunges x 4..."`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make of a chained `map` and `joined` operation to construct a single `String` describing the exercise dictionary for a given exercise. E.g.

```
for routine in routines {
    print("Routine:", routine.routineName)
    print("--------------")
    print(routine.routineExercisesAndSets
        .map { $0 + " x \($1)" }
        .joined(separator: ", "))
    print()
}
/* Routine: Legs
   --------------
   Calf Raises x 4, Squats x 4, Lunges x 4

   Routine: Chest
   --------------
   Bench Press x 4, Press Ups x 4, Flyes x 4, Inclined Bench Press x 4

   Routine: Arms
   --------------
   Tricep Extension x 4, Tricep Dips x 4, Preacher Curls x 4, Hammer Curls x 4, Bicep Curls x 4 

                   */
```

Furthermore, instead of explicitly performing these "presentation" conversions upon each use, you could implement them as the return of the computed `description` property of `Routine`, as a part of letting `Routine` conform to [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customstringconvertible):

```
extension Routine: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return routineName + ":\n" + routineExercisesAndSets
            .map { $0 + " x \($1)" }
            .joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}

for routine in routines {
    print(routine) /* uses Routine:s implementation of 'CustomStringConvertible',
                      the computed property 'description`, specifically           */
    print()
}
/* Legs:
   Calf Raises x 4, Squats x 4, Lunges x 4

   Chest:
   Bench Press x 4, Press Ups x 4, Flyes x 4, Inclined Bench Press x 4

   Arms:
   Tricep Extension x 4, Tricep Dips x 4, Preacher Curls x 4, Hammer Curls x 4, Bicep Curls x 4

                   */
```

---

Given your comment below, it seems as if the properties `routineName` and `routineExercisesAndSets` of `Routine` are optionals. If this is the case, you naturally need to handle unwrapping them prior to accessing their (possibly existing) values. E.g., returning an empty `description` if any of the two properties is `nil`, and otherwise, the combined routine name and details description (as done in the non-optional examples above):

```
struct Routine {
    let routineName: String?
    let routineExercisesAndSets: [String: Int]?
}

extension Routine: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        guard let name = routineName, let details = routineExercisesAndSets else { return "" }
        return name + ":\n" + details.map { $0 + " x \($1)" }.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}
```

Comment: I would always use named parameters

Comment: When trying to use 

`for routine in routines {
    print("Routine:", routine.routineName)
    print("--------------")
    print(routine.routineExercisesAndSets
        .map { $0.0 + " x \($0.1)" }
        .joined(separator: ", "))
    print()
}`

I get an error 'Value of type [String: Int] has no member 0

Comment: This is the exact code that I am using, I have declared the Struct in another file. [This is my code](https://gist.github.com/joshchambers94/56fb38c5cae4e41c22b9b7721c5f623a)

Comment: @MHDev that is not the same example as above: you didn't tell us that your properties were optionals. You naturally need to handle unwrapping these prior to accessing their (possibly existing) values. E.g. using the `nil` coalescing operator: `print(routine.routineExercisesAndSets?
        .map { $0.0 + " x \($0.1)" }
        .joined(separator: ", ") ?? "routineExercisesAndSets is nil")`

Comment: @MHDev included an example in case the properties are optional. You need to decide how you want to handle the presentation of the properties in case one or both of them are `nil`: in the example I added, I simply return an empty `description` (`""`) in case any of them are `nil`.

Comment: Dont know why I didn't think of unwrapping them I was having a major mind block! Sorry for the confusion and thank you for helping me!

Comment: @MHDev happens to the best of us :) happy to help. Have a look also at the `UITableViewCell` additional details included in the bottom of [@appzYourLife:s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40693362/4573247): using the `description` property as the `detailTextLabel`:s `text` property is probably very fit to your purpose based on the tableview image you provided in your question.

Comment: And you can flatMap all the optionals

Comment: Excellent answer. (Voted)

Answer (score 1):

First of all let's conform `Routine` to `CustomStringConvertible`

```
extension Routine: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return routineExercisesAndSets.map { $0 + " x " + $1.description }.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}
```

Now you can easily write

```
routines.forEach { print($0) }
```

Result

```
Calf Raises x 4, Squats x 4, Lunges x 4
Bench Press x 4, Press Ups x 4, Flyes x 4, Inclined Bench Press x 4
Tricep Extension x 4, Tricep Dips x 4, Preacher Curls x 4, Hammer Curls x 4, Bicep Curls x 4
```

Or given a `UITableViewCell`...

```
let cell: UITableViewCell = ...
let routine: Routine = ...
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = routine.description
```

Comment: Note that the `description` wont cover the routine name in this implementation (I included also the routine name in my example of conformance to `CustomStringCovertible` by chained `.map` and `.joined` applied to `routineExercisesAndSets` :) ). But maybe the OP only wants the exercises in the description.

Comment: @dfri: Correct, the `name` of the `routine` is not included in the description in this example.

Comment: ... ellipsis: I wrote my comment prior to(at the exact time of) to the edit addition of the `UITableViewCell` example. With that addition, when applying the `description` to `detailTextLabel`, it would probably be preferable not to include the routine name (Y)